# List with users, with lots of data about those users. How to add the last record from a one to many table to that list for each user?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

My problem:

Each user has multiple contracts (some have 0). I'm trying to get the contract with the highest start date for each user and display it's start and end date in this list.

Model:

```
class Contract(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='contracts')
  contract_start = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
  contract_end = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
```

View:

```
def get(self, request):
  users = User.objects.all().exclude(is_superuser=True)
  return render(request, 'user/list_all.html', {
        'users': users,
    })
```

Template:

```
{% for user in users %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ user.employee.number }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.employee.location }}</td>

    <td>{{ Contract Start }}</td>
    <td>{{ Contract End }}</td>

  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I've been busy with this for a day now but can't seem to solve it. I can not use *distinct()* as I'm using MySQL. I've been trying to use *annotate*, but I either get a queryset with every user in it, while some don't have contracts, or I get the same contract date for every user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you want to get the highest start date that means the latest Contract date

so first we need to get each users's Contracts

then we need to filter the Contracts based on the latest contract_start field 
maybe not the best solution but that what i could get to

View

```
def get(self, request):
  users = User.objects.all().exclude(is_superuser=True)
  data = {}
  for user in users:
    user_contracts = Contract.objects.filter(user=user)
     # edit: to make sure it will not throw matching query does not exist error
    if len(user_contracts ) > 0: 
        user_latest = user_contracts.latest('contract_start')
        data[user] =  user_latest
    else:
        data[user] = ''

  return render(request, 'user/list_all.html', {
        'data': data,
    })
```

Template:

```
{% for user, contract in data.items %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ user.employee.number }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.employee.location }}</td>

    <td>{{ contract.contract_start  }}</td>
    <td>{{ contract.contract_end }}</td>

  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

latest Returns the latest object in the table based on the given field(s).
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest

Comment: I get a "Contract matching query does not exist." error message, problem seems to be in `user_latest = user_contracts.latest('contract_start')`

Comment: It's because the user_contracts is empty

Comment: that means the user doesn't have any Contract
you can make something like 
`if len(user_contracts ) > 0:`

Comment: Where would I put that? Sorry it's been a long day and night

Comment: Awesome that works! This will solve a lot of other problems I have as well. Problem I'm facing with this list now is that it doesn't show any users without a contract anymore, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: you can make else statement to add the user to the data dictionary with empty value

Comment: Awesome, yeah it works as intended now, thanks a million! Edited your comment for future reference.